# in-App purchases work only for sandbox user when installing via TestFlight

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, testflight, in-app

I install my app (built with AppStore profile) via Apple TestFlight. I use REAL account to invite internal tester in TestFlight. My app is installed correctly. When I activate in-app purchase I see Apple's standard dialog "Confirm your In-App purchase" that contains label "[Environment: Sandbox]" but my REAL account (that is used to invite tester) is not accepted. Only manually created in iTunesConnect.com SANDBOX user account accepted. The TestFlight documentaion says that when installing via TestFlight one must use real account.

Maybe this bug cause another one. When I tried to send my app to review it was rejected with explanation "Missing In App Purchase". The reviwer says that he can't see Apple's "Confirm your In-App purchase" dialog when tapping purchase button.

My test configuration is iPad Air 1, iOS 8.3. The app is written on ActionScript and built with AIR SDK 17. I use Adobe standart ProductStore ANE.